# Default servlet getRequestDispatcher of a static page

Tags: tomcat, servlets

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class RootServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String pathInfo = request.getServletPath();
        switch(pathInfo) {
                case "/":
                    this.handleHomePage(request, response);
                    break;
                default:
                    request.getRequestDispatcher(pathInfo).forward(request, response);
            }
    }
```

I'm trying to use a default servlet to catch context root url. So when it's a root url, it will be handled by handleHomePage method. If not, it will be forwarded to the corresponding file. e.g. the css, html, images file. But this will cause a never-ending exception to occur. Does getRequestDispatcher allow forwarding to static page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better to create a filter like this :

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "rootFilter", urlPatterns = { "/*" }, dispatcherTypes = { DispatcherType.REQUEST })
{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest p_oRequest, ServletResponse p_oResponse, FilterChain p_oChain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        // skip non-http requests
        if(!(p_oRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest))
        {
             p_oChain.doFilter(p_oRequest,p_oResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            String pathInfo = ((HttpServletRequest)p_oRequest).getServletPath();
            switch(pathInfo)
            {
                case "/":
                    // Forward to your "root servlet"
                    break;
                default:
                    p_oChain.doFilter(p_oRequest,p_oResponse);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note : this code is untested and not checked for syntax errors.